# Reading a binary file from the file system as a BLOB to use in rhino with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, xlsb

I'm planing to use SheetJS with rhino. And sheetjs takes a binary object(BLOB if i'm correct) as it's input. So i need to read a file from the system using stranded java I/O methods and store it into a blob before passing it to sheetjs. eg :-

```
var XLDataWorkBook = XLSX.read(blobInput, {type : "binary"});
```

So how can i create a BLOB(or appropriate type) from a binary file in java in order to pass it in.

i guess i cant pass streams because i guess XLSX needs a completely created object to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this by myself. i was able to get it done this way.
Read the file with **InputStream** and then write it to a **ByteArrayOutputStream**. like below.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

...

```
buffer.write(bytes, 0, len);
```

Then create a byte array from it.

```
byte[] byteArray =   buffer.toByteArray();
```

Finally i did convert it to a Base64 String (which is also applicable in my case) using the "**Base64.encodeBase64String()**" method in **apache.commons.codec.binary** package. So i can pass **Base64 String** as a method parameter.

If you further need there are lot of libraries(3rd-party and default) available for **Base64 to Blob** conversion as well.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/31842504/7471760